# Add tree item in TreeView dynamically with button

Tags: c#, wpf

My scenario)

```
Add button -> Popup window include input text-box (Name, Position) -> click "done" -> display to node on TreeView.
```

initial TreeView does not have anything. And I click a add button like this:

```
| Name
| - Position
```

Then, I click again add button.

```
| Name
| - Position
| Name
| - Position
```

Is there are an example? I have already many read articles about MVVM TreeView binding. But cannot find a button click to treeview add node dynamically with MVVM.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Bind to an `ObservableCollection<T>` and add an item to it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your TreeView's name is `myTreeView` , On button click event:

```
var item = new TreeViewItem("Name");
var subItem = new TreeViewItem("Position")
item.Items.Add(subItem);
myTreeView.Items.Add(item);
```